# CORS error when adding Azure AD authentication

Tags: c#, angular, azure-active-directory, angular7, .net-core-2.1

Trying to add Azure AD authentication to an Angular 7 webapp with a .net core 2.1 backend.

However, I get the CORS error during the request.

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/.......' (redirected from 'https://localhost:5001/api/auth/login') from origin 'https://localhost:5001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

So I tried adding some CORS policy in the startup pipe-line.

**Startup.cs**

```
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }    

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(config => config
             .AddPolicy("SiteCorsPolicy", builder => builder
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowCredentials()
              )
           ); // <--- CORS policy - allow all for now

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;                
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_AD_DOMAIN.onmicrosoft.com";   // ad domain            
                options.ClientId = "my_client_id"; // client guid
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
                options.CallbackPath = "/auth/signin-callback";
                options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:5000";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
            }).AddCookie();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseCors("SiteCorsPolicy"); // <--- CORS policy
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**angular auth service**

```
login() {        
    const url = this.baseUrl + "api/auth/login";
    this._http.get(url).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

Or am I going the wrong way about it? Should I use some third pary "ADAL" npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-angular) to extract the token from the client side and then pass the token to the server for validation?

If I navigate to the login URL, e.g: localhost:5000/api/auth/login --> I get set off to the AAD login page, and redirected back at successful authentication. But if I trigger it from code, I get the CORS error.

Comment: is your xhr configured `withCredentials` bc that doesn't work with cookies

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't think so, how do I check that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach is a bit wrong.
You've configured OIDC + Cookies, yet want to call it with an XHR.

The typical approach would be to:

- Configure JWT Bearer token authentication on the API
- Use ADAL/MSAL on the front-end to authenticate the user + acquire an access token for the back-end
- Attach the access token to XHRs so they are authenticated

Some samples/articles that may help:

- https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi
- https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/MSALAngularDemoApp
- https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2
- https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-authentication-aspnet-core-api-part-1
- https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-authentication-aspnet-core-api-part-2

Keep in mind ADAL can only be used with the AAD v1 endpoint and MSAL with the v2 endpoint.